How to use a variable in React updated by an outside process
I'm currently learning how to use function components in react and got a bit of a timing problem. As it seems, the event that should trigger a rerender is called between the rendering of the component and the call to the useEffect hook. Is there any delay between those two that would allow an async event to be executed? And how would I prevent this "gap"? (I do not remember about every having such a problem with class components and the componentDidMount function for registering my eventListener back then).
Given this component (with very simplified types and logic):
// global variable. May have already been updated from before CounterDisplay is even rendered the first time
let globallyStoredCounter = 0; 

export default function CounterDisplay(): React.JSX.Element {
    useEvent('counter_changed_event');

    console.log('Start rendering CounterDisplay: ', globallyStoredCounter);
    return (
        <div>{globallyStoredCounter}</div>
    );
}

with this custom event hook:
export function useEvent(eventName: string) {
    const [lastEventInstance, setEventInstance] = useState<object>({});

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleEvent(event: object) {
            console.log('Trigger a rerender by updating the state with a new object');
            setEventInstance(event);
        }

        console.log('Listening to event ' + eventName);
        window.addEventListener(eventName, handleEvent);
        return () => {
            console.log('Stop listening to event');
            window.removeEventListener(eventName, handleEvent);
        };
    }, [lastEventInstance]);
    return [lastEventInstance];
}

and finally, the code to dispatch the event. This is executed by the same button press, that also triggers the CounterDisplay Component to render.
fetch('http://localhost/api/something').then(_ => {
   globallyStoredCounter += 1;
   console.log(`Notifying event "counter_changed_event" with data`, {counter: globallyStoredCounter});
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event('counter_changed_event'));
}); 

I get this output in the console:
> Start rendering CounterDisplay: 0
> Notifying event "counter_changed_event" with data {counter: 1}
> Listening to event counter_changed_event

While the HTML output keeps showing the value 0.
And to be clear: Yes, the {counter: 1} object is an entirely new object that is definitely, even shallowly, different from the previous.
I hope someone can help me with this, as this is at the moment a nasty race condition.

Edit: As it seemed like I did not explain my problem very well (sorry for that!), I updated the code above to include how the event will be called and here is some more Info, that will (hopefully) make it more clear:
The Situation:
I got the component and hook as described above and want to always display the current value of my globallyStoredCounter (it should not matter, when it was or will be updated). The counter itself is updated asynchronously and triggers the event listener afterwards.
My expectation vs reality:
If globallyStoredCounter is updated externally BEFORE rendering the component, it shows the updated number.
If globallyStoredCounter is updated AFTER applying the useEvent hook, it shows the updated number.
But sometimes, the event is called between rendering and the event listener in the useEffect hook being placed, thus not updating the component.
The question:
Im surely not the first or only one with independently updated data and a component to reflect this data. But I do not know how to keep the component updated, if a change is happening between rendering and the useEffect hook. Can anyone tell me, how to avoid this gap and keep showing the correct number?

Sorry, I don't quite understand your post/question nor do I see what your code example is to be demonstrating. Can you [edit] to clarify what issue you are asking for help resolving?

Are you asking if it's possible for an event to occur in before your useEffect sets up the listener? If so, yes, it is possible. You'd need to show precisely how you're triggering that event to get any real advice though.

@DrewReese I edited the question and the code to hopefully explain my situation more clearly. In short: I would like to know how to reliably react to changes in global data that can occur while rendering the component.

@rschristian Yes, that was the first part of my question, thanks! Sorry, I was unclear about the problem. The follow-up question would then be, how to react to such timings. I edited the question and included how the listener will be called.

Are you basically asking how to capture events from prior to the event listener being instantiated in a React component after the initial render cycle after the component mounted? I don't think there's much you can do here. Using the useLayoutEffect might help a little, but the basic problem is that you can't handle events from before the listener callback being instantiated. If handling these events if mission critical then move the listeners higher up the ReactTree.

If you store a variable outside of the component (and React) you'll have to do a lot of work to make sure the updates are picked up correctly and component lifecycle behaviours might change between React versions.
I'd strongly suggest trying to find a solution within React to store your variable, be it a prop, state, context, etc.
If you clarify why you need that globallyStoredCounter outside of the component and updated elsewhere, me or someone else can help with concrete code solution.

The  globallyStoredCounter is outside the component, because it originates from another library, that operates over time in the background. I attempted to use this event driven approach to avoid having to implement React into the other program or vice versa and instead only trigger changes by sending events. This would also help, as I got components like this multiple times on the page and would have to pass the data over a lot of props down to the individual components.
The page itself is not very dynamic otherwise, so the downside being hard to track is not much of a problem

Hmm, then you'll probably need to manually force an update of the component with a fake useState or useReducer call, see official docs: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate

Actually, is there a reason why you can't integrate your library with a Context? https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

I just had to read into React contexts (didn't know about them before!) and this seems like a fitting solution to my problem. I will try it out tomorrow as soon as I can and if everything works, accept this answer!

So what I did end up doing, was using react contexts as dain suggested in this answer (after I learned that such a thing exists) by creating a wrapper component like this:
export const LibContext = createContext({
    counter: globallyStoredCounter
});

export default function LibContextWrapper(props: {children: ReactNode;}): React.JSX.Element {
    useEvent('counter_changed_event');

    return (
        <LibContext.Provider value={{
            counter: globallyStoredCounter,
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </LibContext.Provider>
    );
}

Then I wrapped my application with this context and was able to use the context in just the relevant components by simply adding (const libContext = useContext(LibContext)), without resorting to the excessive use of props all over the page. Because the wrapper is already mounted, long before the event will be called, it can include the external data into react and allow the components to update without any uncovered time.
Also, there will always be only one single interface to the external data, which makes it easy to track down in the future.
Links to the docs:

https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context
https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#updating-data-passed-via-context


If you need to run code synchronously before the component renders, you can use the useLayoutEffect hook instead of useEffect
